# CCavenues Error Code:10001 invalid request

Tags: php

I integrated ccavenues payment gateway to client website...

For few of users payment is debited from their account and redirected to success page.

For few of others payment is debited and stopped in middle with error Oops:Error Code:10001 Invalid Request-Encrypted request invalid/not present.. ( it is not redirected to success page..)
Code of reponse:

```
$workingKey='XXX';      //Working Key should be provided here.
$encResponse=$_POST["encResp"];         //This is the response sent by the CCAvenue Server
$rcvdString=decrypt($encResponse,$workingKey);      //Crypto Decryption used as per the specified working key.
$order_status="";
$decryptValues=explode('&', $rcvdString);
$dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);
echo "<center>";

for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
{
    $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
    if($i==3)   $order_status=$information[1];
}

if($order_status==="Success")
{
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "payment_success.php";</script>';
}
else if($order_status==="Aborted")
{
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "payment_abort.php";</script>';


}
else if($order_status==="Failure")
{
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "payment_fail.php";</script>';

}
else
{
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "payment_secure.php";</script>';


}

echo "</center>";
```

If any problem is there it should also not allowed to accept all payments,,

Can any one,Please save my day..

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @kursad please review the code and make help

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy. I hope someone will help you.